# Fix header position when scrolling

Tags: html, css

i want to fix the header so it will be there even if i scrolled down 
i tried to use position:fixed

```
    <header style="margin-bottom: 1cm; position: fixed;  ">
        <div style="float:left;" align="left">Instagram User Explorer</div>
            <div align="center">
                <form name="contact" id="contact" method="get">
                Search : <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"/>
                <input type="button" value="search!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
    </header>
```

but the textfield and button wnt down i dont know why
[image]

and what i want is to be in the same line

```
    <header style="margin-bottom: 1cm;">
        <div style="float:left;" align="left">Instagram User Explorer</div>
            <div align="center">
                <form name="contact" id="contact" method="get">
                Search : <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"/>
                <input type="button" value="search!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
                </form>
            </div>
    </header>
```

like this :
[image]

how to do it ?

Comment: width: 100%; add that as well to position: fixed

Comment: @erikrunia tried it and it works but this is will stop margin-bottom: 1cm; and i have another tags after the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/kggfLaqo/1/)

you need to do a little more work with css to get that effect, the background is just added for visibility in the fiddle. your body needs a margin that can clear the fixed header as well, as seen in .body class below

```
.header {
    height: 50px; 
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #ddd;
    top: 0;
}

.body {
    margin-top: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<header style="margin-bottom: 1cm;">
    <div style="float:left;">Instagram User Explorer</div>
        <div style="float:right;">
            <form name="contact" id="contact" method="get">
            Search : <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"/>
            <input type="button" value="search!" name="submit" id="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
</header>
```